# How merge prev/next lists in python?

Tags: python, list, merge

I have lists of exactly two *previous* and *next* items.

```
[['Robert','Christopher'],['John','Eric'],['Mark','John'],['Mickael','Robert']]
```

For the first list, 'Robert' is *previous* and 'Christopher' *next*.

I would like to merge them having the lowest *previous* and the highest *next* by keeping the continuity of the final lists. 
Result can be:

```
[['Mickael','Christopher'],['Mark','Eric']]
```

or

```
[['Mark','Eric'],['Mickael','Christopher']]
```

The result is two lists because there are no continuity between these two lists.
*previous* and *next* cannot be sorted (For example 'Mickael' is before 'Christopher'). There are no loops and no repeated elements (i.e. 'Robert' is always before 'Christopher', 'John' is always before 'Eric'...) so this is a topological graph

**Is it possible easily in python?**

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409486/how-can-i-order-a-list-of-connections

Comment: You are basically looking for the start and end points for possible paths through a graph here.

Comment: Do you've loops in your data, for example : `[A,B], [B,A], [C,D]`?
this will result in (A,A), (C,D).

Comment: No i will not have loops. 'A' will always be before than 'B', 'B' before than 'C'... Nevertheless, I can have different orders for these couples: [B,C], [A,B], [C,D], [F,G], [E,F]

Comment: @ChristopheSaugé Then see the solutions on the link I posted earlier.

Comment: This is a kind of solution but i do not have any loops as the link refers to. The solution could be simpler i think (use of dictionary seems useless)

Comment: @ChristopheSaugé Your question is a graph related problem, for finding paths dicts are going to be the most appropriate data structures here.
And my [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16409770/846892) on that page works fine for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [How can I order a list of connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16409486/how-can-i-order-a-list-of-connections) Ashwini Chaudhary's link (thx Ashwini), i have written a solution which fits my needs:

```
items= [['F','G'], ['B','C'], ['A','B'], ['C','D'], ['E','F']]
mydict = dict(items)
for prev,next in items:
    if next in mydict:
        mydict[prev] = mydict[next]
        del mydict[next]
print(list(mydict.items()))
```

Result is:

```
[('A', 'D'), ('E', 'G')]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work, and be quite efficient:

```
items = [['A','B'], ['B','C'], ['C','E'], ['E','F'], ['F','G']]
nodes = dict(items)
changed = True
while changed:
    changed = False
    keys = nodes.keys()
    for prevEl in keys:
        if not prevEl in nodes: #may have been deleted
            continue
        nextEl = nodes[prevEl]
        if nextEl in nodes:
            tmp = nodes[nextEl]
            del nodes[nextEl]
            nodes[prevEl] = tmp
            changed = True
```

Comment: It does not work with: items= [['F','G'], ['B','C'], ['A','B'], ['C','D'], ['E','F']]

Comment: items cannot be sorted. I will edit my topic to be more clear.

Comment: Can you have repeated elements? For example:
 items = [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['B', 'D'], ['C', 'D']

Comment: I'm not allowed to comment on the answer below, but it gives the wrong answer for [['G','D'], ['E','F'], ['F','G']]. It gives [('A', 'D'), ('E', 'G')] instead of [('E', 'D')].